# how to sort a column using a custom order in amazon athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

to sort this column

```
a
b
c
```

to get this output

```
b
a
c
```

the mysql clause `order by field(col,'b','a','c')` does not work in athena. is there an equivalent?

Comment: order by b,a,c should work. Further you can add desc in case you want to sort in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case when` for getting this order:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col='b' THEN 1
   WHEN col='a' THEN 2
   WHEN col='c' THEN 3
   ELSE 4 END ASC
```

Comment: @jikohel286 Why not? you can still have multiple columns in your order by. The question was specifically asking to sort one column with values in a specific order.